# Viewing messages that were sent to non existent email user Centos 7

Tags: email, centos-7

Is there a way of viewing emails that were sent to a non-existent user's address on the server?

I have a user with email `example@domain.com` and I want to get all images that were sent to this address while address wasn't registered on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your MTA is specifically configured to deliver non-existent messages to a different or a default e-mail account, you can't.

Usually MTAs are not configured this way, and the incoming message is rejected with a `5XX` code, which means it is a hard bounce (so if the client honors the corresponding RFC, it shouldn't try to re-send the message), and the message gets lost.